# How to fetch Deleted accounts form salesforce using API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, salesforce

I am integrating salesforce with an ERP. One of the requirement is to synchronize Accounts form salesforce to ERP. I am using Salesforce API to fetch the accounts from salesforce. But it only fetches the accounts with isDeleted false. How can I fgetch Deleted accounts form salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [queryAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm#!) rather than query, which'll include deleted accounts in the results. Or you can use the getDeleted call to fetch just the deleted accounts.